# Uvicorn & asyncio: how can OSErrors with asyncio-only stack trace be caught?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn

I have an API server that runs asynchronous functions using FastAPI & uvicorn on Windows. Every now and then the program throws a network error via asyncio that causes the API to become unresponsive, but can't be caught by my script. I'd like to be able to put a trycatch somewhere that will catch this type of error so I can shut down & restart the server, but the traceback for the error doesn't have any of my code in it.

The following is a simple example to illustrate the file structure; first the file `app.py` defines the API:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/check-status")
async def root():
    return {"Alive": True}
```

the server parameters are defined in a `config.json`:

```
{
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 80
}
```

then the server is launched programmatically from another script `run_app.py`, with a trycatch block that should catch any errors thrown during the execution, show it on the console, and restart:

```
import uvicorn
import json
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('path/to/config.json', 'r') as f:
        config = uvicorn.Config(**json.load(f))
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    try:
        server.run()
    except Exception as e:
        err_timestamp = datetime.now().ctime()
        print(f'{err_timestamp}: Exception raised\n{e}\nRestarting...')
        server.shutdown()
        server.run()
```

However, the server still ends up crashing after the following error:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-33094' coro=<IocpProactor.accept.<locals>.accept_coro() done, defined at C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py:563> exception=OSError(22, 'The specified network name is no longer available', None, 64, None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 566, in accept_coro
    await future
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 555, in finish_accept
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available

Accept failed on a socket
socket: <asyncio.TransportSocket fd=732, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 80)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 818, in loop
    conn, addr = f.result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 566, in accept_coro
    await future
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 812, in _poll
    value = callback(transferred, key, ov)
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 555, in finish_accept
    ov.getresult()
OSError: [WinError 64] The specified network name is no longer available
```

Clearly, the error happens purely within `asyncio`, and isn't actually thrown at any point in the execution of my code, so I haven't been able to replicate this error myself to test a solution. I know this type of WinError is usually down to network issues and isn't something that can actually be solved by the API, but I need to at least be able to deal with it when it occurs.

Environment; Python 3.8.10, Uvicorn version 0.17.4, FastAPI version 0.73.0, Windows 10

Comment: I have noticed this in Windows as well.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing it right now

Comment: @link we figured out that the problem was coming from external machines (probably scammers/bots) pinging the server, so the problem was solved by restricting the machines allowed to open connections with the API to a fixed list of known IP addresses. However I never found a solution that would allow you to get around this problem at the Python level...

Comment: We don't have a problem with spammers and bots, it's just us doing the testing on the Windows server. It still throws me this error and I can't figure it out. We have an Antivirus installed. Could this be the reason? Some of the articles point to this.

Answer (score 0):

The described error is a result of a Python bug; the possible fix for the `asyncio` code is described in the issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/93821.

Hopefully, the fix will be applied soon.